# How to stay logged in when switching URLs ("same web app" for both URLs)

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3, federated-identity

The ASP.NET MVC 3 site I am developing can be accessed from multiple different URLs, each of which connect it to different databases on the back-end (1:1 URL to DB).  I need to be able to allow the user to switch between URLs without having to log into each URL.  Currently, I'm using Forms Auth with an almost standard MembershipProvider/RoleProvder scheme.

What are my options for allowing the change of URL and "staying logged in"?  I'm guessing I need to implement some sort of federated security.  What do you recommend?  Note that I would need to control all aspects of the security (so, for example, can't use google id).

If necessary, I'm ok with adding a WCF web service to the mix.

I do not want to integrate with AD if at all possible since we don't want all the web users as domain users.

**EDIT**: the authentication DB is currently the same across all URLs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify: when you say "different URLs", do you mean "different domains"?

Comment: yes, different domains.  for example "cpl.domainone.com" and "cpl.domaintwo.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, I'm pretty sure you're flat out of luck. The membership provider persists the authentication session via cookies which, of course, are bound to the domain. Short of implementing a behaviour which would allow you to pass - and verify - auth state via the URL, I can't see any way around this.

Comment: I'm open to ditching the membership provider scheme and session cookies in favor of another alternative if that will do the trick.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can ditch session cookies and use cookiless session persistence (uses the URL instead), but I'm not sure this will maintain auth state across domains and it's NOT very nice from a security perspective (see here: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html). I wouldn't ditch the membership provider simply because it's so fully featured, well proven and it's extensible anyway (you can override all the native behaviours). Can you possibly update your question to explain more about why you're using multiple domains? There might be another angle to this.